# How to draw to the full window in rgl?

Tags: r, rgl

I am drawing 4 subfigures in rgl to a window, and I would like them to fill the available space:

```
library(rgl);
rgl::open3d(windowRect = c(0,50, 1200, 1200));
rgl::mfrow3d(2, 2);


rgl::next3d(reuse=FALSE);
rgl::bg3d("yellow");

rgl::next3d(reuse=FALSE);
rgl::bg3d("blue");

rgl::next3d(reuse=FALSE);
rgl::bg3d("red");

rgl::next3d(reuse=FALSE);
rgl::bg3d("green");
```

However, the result uses only a tiny potion of the window, it looks like this:

[image: Result of the code given above]

How can I make the 4 colored areas span the whole window, instead of only using the tiny part in the lower left corner?

Comment: Observation; when I run the code line by line it executes as expected but running all the code as one block I get the same image as you. Adding `Sys.sleep(1)` after the `rgl::open3d()` line allows for the code to be run as one chunk with correct output ... so

Comment: @user20650 Thanks, your comment helped me fix it. I had to add `Sys.sleep(1)` also after the call to `rgl::mfrow3d()` though. Would you add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @user20650 Hm, wait. When running the same code again (with the waits), it stops working. I cannot get it to work another time right now, no matter how often I run the code that worked once. Maybe I will have to report this as a bug or ask on the mailing list.

Comment: it works repeatedly for me, but it does hint to some other issue.Yes , I think the R list would be a good place to list

Comment: I have found a solution. The idea came from [this ML post from 2008 about an rgl bug](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-September/174191.html). Maybe it was never fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tools me hours, but I have finally managed to get this to work reliably by myself. It seems you have to call par3d() after open3d().

Also note the call to Sys.sleep, as suggested by user20650 in the comments above. Without it, the window only gets drawn in full size after clicking on it (on my machine?).

Full working code:

```
rgloptions = list("windowRect"=c(50,50,1000,1000));

rgl::open3d();
do.call(rgl::par3d, rgloptions);
Sys.sleep(1);
rgl::mfrow3d(2, 2);

rgl::next3d(reuse=FALSE);
rgl::bg3d("yellow");

rgl::next3d(reuse=FALSE);
rgl::bg3d("blue");

rgl::next3d(reuse=FALSE);
rgl::bg3d("red");

rgl::next3d(reuse=FALSE);
rgl::bg3d("green");
```

This gives the following output reliably:

[image]

Comment: Good you found a solution spirit, but it does suggest something is not quite correct with the code that you have to do this -- particularly the sleep. I do think you should post on R-help. Duncan Murdoch, the package author is active and helpful.

Comment: I also had that idea. The package seems to be used quite a bit, and while there even are `Sys.sleep` calls in a few of the official package examples, as I have found, it feels strange that this is needed. Others should have complained about it already. Will do.

Comment: The problem is that the `windowRect` setting doesn't propagate immediately to the `viewport` setting.  A workaround is to specify both, e.g.`rgl::open3d(windowRect = c(0,50, 1200, 1200), viewport = c(0,0,1200,1150))`.

Comment: I think I tried setting the viewport as well. This resulted in an image in which a single rectangle filled the whole viewport, and they were drawn one over the other. I.e., in the end I got an all-green screen. I'll check again later. Maybe something else was off with that version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is an exact solution that you're looking for, but running your code as a function has worked for me.

```
make_box <- function(){library(rgl)
 rgl::open3d(windowRect = c(0,50, 1200, 1200))
 rgl::mfrow3d(2, 2)


 rgl::next3d(reuse=FALSE)
 rgl::bg3d("yellow")

 rgl::next3d(reuse=FALSE)
 rgl::bg3d("blue")

 rgl::next3d(reuse=FALSE)
 rgl::bg3d("red")

 rgl::next3d(reuse=FALSE)
 rgl::bg3d("green")}
 make_box()
```

Comment: This does not make a difference for me, the result is identical to not calling it in a function. But thanks for trying. Apparently the cause are some sort of timing issues, maybe caused by delay introduced by the window manager or whatever. See the comment by user20650 above.